# Border color order

Tags: html, css

I have a table with every border set to 1px width solid.
I want the top, left and bottom border to be black, and the right border to be white.
So, i used this css code

```
border-right-color: white;    
border-left-color: black; 
border-top-color: black; 
border-bottom-color: black; 
border: solid 1px;
```

The problem comes in IE9, where the top right corner pixel will be white, but the bottom right corner will be black.

I suspect the problem comes form the way IE9 reorganize the style, because when i look at the css of my table in the developper tools console, it is ordered like this :

```
border-top-color: black;
border-right-color: white; 
border-bottom-color: black;  
border-left-color: black; 
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
```

This let me think that, maybe, the order used to defined colors makes it so the top border is colored black, then the right border is colored white (overwritting the top right corner), then the bottom border is colored black (overwritting the bottom right corner) and finnaly the left border is colored left.

The thing is that, on a white background, the top and bottom borders do not appear to be the same length (by one pixel). It may not be much, but I need those two borders to fit with other lines on my page.

So, how could i fix this? Is it really about the order the borders are colored, and if it is, how could I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, here it is, pretty simple in fact

```
border: solid 1px black;
border-right-style: hidden;
```

By giving the right border a style hidden, it works perfectly now. The thing is that a border with style hidden will precede on any other style for collapsed or overlying borders.

Comment: Browsers draw a diagonal line fom the outer corner to the inner corner where the color shift occurs. If the border-width is set to 1px, the browser cannot split it so IE chooses the top right pixel to be white, FF - the bottom right. CSS3 spec doesn't say how the browser should handle joins. By removing the right border the diagonal isn't rendered. You can see it better if you set height:0; and try to make some CSS triangles.

Comment: `border-right-style: hidden` is basically `border-right-style: none` for non-tables. See if `border-right-color: transparent` produces anything different?

Comment: Is it possibly so that you don't actually want the right border to be white at all, but actually invisible (same as the background) or no border at all?

Comment: Yes, i want it to either be transparent, or the same color as the background. I have to do both because `border-style: hidden` doesn't work in some versions of IE.

Comment: @Shadowxvii: Then it's simple. Just specify no border for the right side: `border-style: solid none solid solid;`.

Answer (score 21):

The order that you sprecify the border colors is irrelevant. Browsers simply display the borders in different ways. The pixels in the corner get the color from either of the sides, and it depends on what browser you are using.

There are several different methods used. Here are the most common browsers, and how they draw the corners:

**Internet Explorer:**

```
+----------------------+--+
|                      |  |
+----------------------|  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  +----------------------+
|  |                      |
+--+----------------------+
```

**Firefox:**

```
+--+----------------------+
|  |                      |
|  +----------------------+
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
+----------------------|  |
|                      |  |
+----------------------+--+
```

**Chrome:**

```
+--+----------------------+
|  |                      |
|  |----------------------+
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  +----------------------+
|  |                      |
+--+----------------------+
```

**Safari:**

```
+--+-------------------+--+
|  |                   |  |
|  |-------------------|  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  +-------------------+  |
|  |                   |  |
+--+-------------------+--+
```

**Opera:**

```
+-------------------------+
|                         |
+-------------------------+
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  |                   |  |
|  +-------------------+  |
|  |                   |  |
+--+-------------------+--+
```

It looks almost as if different browser vendors went out of their way to use a method that is different from all other browsers...

(Tested in recent versions. Older versions of any browser might possibly do it differently, but that's not really important as they differ so much anyway.)

So, if you need full control over how the corners are drawn, you get to use two elements inside each other, put vertical borders on one and horisontal borders on the other.

Comment: +1 this is a nice answer. Do you have any sources you got this information from?

Comment: @Christoph: I made a test page, and tested it in different browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Ksdjs/

Comment: awwww, this is horrible:-D Do you have eagle eyes?

Comment: This. The specification doesn't seem to clarify how conflicts at the corners should be resolved, so each browser chose its own implementation. And @Christoph: most browsers have a zoom function built-in. ;-)

Comment: @Christoph: There is an accessory in Windows called Magnifier. :)

Comment: after using the magnifier at 400% i discovered, that Ch19 actually uses neither of these methods xD

Comment: @MattiasBuelens The browser zoom function is useless, because it scales the border, resulting in a multi-pixel border with the sole pixel being the same size as in the unzoomed version.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, though i'll be using another solution than what you suggested.

Comment: Very visualized explain but I think the way browser shows now is a little different, at least for Chrome, there is no priority anymore, corners are splitted in halves

Comment: @DuTran: Some browsers are likely to have changed in the last 9 years, but I think (without checking) that there are still differences. As pixels can't be split in halves, do you know how Chrome draws the corner pixel?

Comment: @Guffa what I mean is that instead of one border covers the whole corner, the 4 corners are now splitted diagonally, like how they make the frame of a picture

Comment: @DuTran: That's when you have a border that is more than one pixel wide. This is about how the borders are placed when the border is one pixel wide.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
div{
 border:1px solid black;
 border-right-color:white;
}
```

Comment: That is what i had before. It seems like IE9 reorganize it for himself before rendering the page.